# How to defend against adblock detection/adblock subscription leaks?

Tags: spoofing, identity, fingerprinting, fingerprint, identification

Is there a best practice (or useful extension) for defending against adblock fingerprinting techniques? I'm not asking about how to bypass adblock detection as such, but rather how one might appear invisible (or spoof one's identity) to these systems? For example, [Browserleaks](https://browserleaks.com/proxy) knows my adblock type and even my subscriptions to the various adblock lists:

[image]

How I can prevent my browser from leaking this sensitive information to various websites or prevent ad block detection in a more general sense?

None of the solutions I've encountered actually address the root of the problem. That includes turning off JavaScript, using custom filters, as well as installing numerous anti-adblock extensions. I thought I solved this problem, for instance, with Nano adblocker. With this extension, I can prevent Browserleaks and other sites from detecting adblockers, but that isn't always the case. Other sites, such as inoreader.com, seem to have better detection methods. It's real asshole design, honestly.